# Indicator-cpufreq

Tags: indicator

I'm a new Linux user and I'm having a bad time trying to make "indicator-cpufreq" work. It just doesn't show up on my bar, what am I doing wrong?
I want to use it to set my CPU to maximum performance. Is there any other software I can use or should I fix this one?
Thanks

I'm running the last version of Ubuntu ( 15 ). It is up to date

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu adjusts the clock rate automatically as per the requirement. If any of your process needs higher clock rate to run optimally , it will be achieved. You can monitor the performance using the tool call Psensor.

The installation procedure is thus:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors hddtemp
sudo sensors-detect
sudo service kmod start
sudo apt-get install psensor
```